# eventhandler for a list of pictureboxes

Tags: c#, .net, event-handling

I have a list of pictureBoxes that created at run-time. 
How can I define same eventhandlers (same mousemove event, for example) for each picturebox in the list?

I use C# in Visual Studio .net 4

Thanks for every help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox_events.aspx all events  supported by PictureBox can be found here

**For e.g**

```
pictureBox[0].MouseMove += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(pictureBox_MouseMove);

protected void pictureBox_MouseMove(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
{
//...
}
```

Comment: Are there any way to distinguish between pictureboxes in the protected void pictureBox_MouseMove ?

Comment: @JleruOHeP is right you will need to cast the sender to picturebox

Answer (score 0):

What about simple

```
PictureBox pb = new PictureBox();
pb.MouseMove += new EventHandler(MyHandler_Click);
```

And your handler:

```
private void MyHandler_Click(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
{
   //your code
}
```

Comment: I use lists. for example: List<picturebox> pb = new List<picturebox>();

Comment: @johnsmith: this is very trivial, do like you normally would traverse a list. You could add the eventhandler like JleruOHeP is doing and then add it to the list. Or loop over the list and add the EventHandler.